# Universal Modules GUI Design

Tags: design, gui, architectural-patterns

PROBLEM: GUI built above database entities usually consist of creator window (pane etc.), editor window, maybe grid or other view window. To represent an entity for user it usually requires building several predefined windows, and the same for each one. Entitites and its fields could not be in similar relations to treat them generally.

RESEARCH: There are GUI approaches like Pivot Table that allow developing one module to represent any underlying data.

QUESTION: Is there a project design approach that helps building one module to dynamically represent any data (by user), or is it impossible? Example applications or why is it used so rarely?